# Netty 4.1 - not a WebSocket handshake request: missing upgrade

Tags: java, http, websocket, netty

I want to support both `ws`and `http` but stucked into this problem.
I tried to access `/` but netty responses http 400 with message.

> not a WebSocket handshake request: missing upgrade

This is log from `http://localhost:9001/`  request from Chrome browser.

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:9001
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.110 Safari/537.36
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: ko-KR,ko;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
Cookie: csrftoken=G86EVdqbL8NUfqex8N8gZ9QzPc6dj6Jd
content-length: 0, 0B
15:56:07.998 DEBUG io.netty.handler.codec.http.websocketx.WebSocketServerHandshaker[debug:81] - [id: 0xd2bd692e, L:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:9001 - R:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:53677] WebSocket version V00 server handshake
15:56:07.998 INFO  io.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler[info:101] - [id: 0xd2bd692e, L:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:9001 - R:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:53677] WRITE: DefaultFullHttpResponse(decodeResult: success, version: HTTP/1.1, content: UnpooledHeapByteBuf(ridx: 0, widx: 50, cap: 50/50))
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request, 50B
```

and code snippets.

```
p.addLast(new HttpServerCodec())
        .addLast(new HttpObjectAggregator(65536))
        .addLast( new LoggingHandler(LogLevel.INFO))
        /**
         * For websocket chatting
         */
        .addLast(new WebSocketServerProtocolHandler("/chat"))
        .addLast(new WsUserAcceptHandler())
        .addLast(new WsChatServerHandler())
        /**
         * For accessing / or HTTP 404 
         */
        .addLast(new HttpStaticFileHandler("/", ChatServer.index))
        .addLast(new HttpNotFoundHandler());
```

at this log line, I don't understand why netty tried to websocket handshaking?

```
io.netty.handler.codec.http.websocketx.WebSocketServerHandshaker[debug:81] - [id: 0xd2bd692e, L:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:9001 - R:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:53677] WebSocket version V00 server handshake
```

Comment: Isn't this a dube of your other question? [missing upgrade : Serve both http and ws on netty 4.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36415821)

Comment: @Ferrybig Yes. It's my question but it reads few too much and no answers so I uploaded new question again. Is this having any problem(or panelty) using SO?

Comment: are you using netty version 4.1.0.CR4 resp. 4.0.35 or newer? previously WebSocketServerProtocolHandshakeHandler grabbed all the request, now it will only grab those matching the websocket path, see https://github.com/netty/netty/commit/2e6544fc0e2581f96652be02d86e777e8e0493bc resp. https://github.com/netty/netty/commit/68bbd4e9669aab4c29dcc1d23ef331aaa2aee333

Comment: @h4ssi Oh thanks. I found already, you're right. I used order than. When I changed library version, It works well!